# Create ggplot2 chart with y scale starting at zero AND dollar formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a scatter plot using packages ggplot2 and scales. I can get the plot to EITHER have a Y axis beginning at zero OR have a y axis formatted as a currency value. I cannot get it do to both.

This code correctly formats the Y scale to O, but expresses the Y scale in notational form:

```
age_chart %>% ggplot(aes(x = `Patient Age`, y=Total))+
  geom_point(alpha = .5)+
  geom_smooth()+
  xlab('Age')+
  ylab('Total Plan Pmt')+
  ggtitle('Total Plan Payment by Patient Age')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(prefix="$"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  ylim(0,NA)
```

If I comment out the last row the plot correctly formats the Y scale as currency, but has a minimum value below 0.

```
age_chart %>% ggplot(aes(x = `Patient Age`, y=Total))+
  geom_point(alpha = .5)+
  geom_smooth()+
  xlab('Age')+
  ylab('Total Plan Pmt')+
  ggtitle('Total Plan Payment by Patient Age')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(prefix="$"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  #ylim(0,NA)
```

Question: How can I create a Y axis beginning at 0 and formatted as currency?
Thanks you.

Comment: Could you try `scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(prefix="$"), limits = c(0,NA)` without the `ylim(0,NA)`?

Comment: @teunbrand Not the first time I see you giving a spot-on answer in the comments. :-) Maybe care to turn it into a post? It would keep this thread out of "answers:0" filters...

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

Use the following:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(prefix="$"), limits = c(0,NA)
```

and leave out

```
ylim(0,NA)
```

Longer answer:

There are multiple ways for ggplot to handle limits on positional scales.

- Using `xlim()` or `ylim()`
- Using `scale_x/y_continuous()` or discrete, or datetime etc.
- Using `coord_*(xlim = ..., ylim = ...)`

However, if you supply multiple to ggplot, it doesn't know which one the user wants and picks the last one of `scale_x/y_continous` and `xlim/ylim`. These limits affect *how* things are drawn, i.e. everything that is out of bounds will be censored by default. `coord_*()` works differently and affects *what* is drawn, it doesn't censor but can clip datapoints that are outside of panel limits.

Now in your case specifically, the plot forgets what it learned about the y-axis (`labels = dollar_format(prefix="$")`) because you supplied a new argument for the y-axis (`ylim`), replacing the old one. If you find running into this problem frequently, I would suggest to use the more verbose `scale_x/y_continuous/discrete()` option by default.